# What game is shown on this Steam 2021 Winter Sale thumbnail?

Tags: game-identification

The 'Open World Games' category for the Steam winter sale has the below image for its thumbnail, but I can't identify the game. What game is it from?

[image: Steam Thumbnail]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That appears to be the game [Among Trees](https://store.steampowered.com/app/897730/Among_Trees/). One of the images on the website contains an exact image:

[image: petting fox in Among Trees]

I located this by navigating to Steam, finding the image you posted, and doing a reverse image search on their [promo image](https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/store/promo/winter2021/genre_tiles/genre_tile_open_world.png?v=1) image without the text